# Xamarin iOS - How to make sure messaging app is up to date?

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, messaging

I have set background fetch to the app. But, It is not called all the time (it depends on how often the app is used by the user)

This is what want to do: When someone send a message to me, I need to make sure that my phone receives the message. Right now, I am using APNS (which works well is the phone is online and working). But, let's say the phone is off or internet not working, the user will never know that a new message has been received, unless he opens the app.

Is there anyway to make sure that, as soon as the user CAN be informed that a new message has been sent, a notification will be displayed on his phone? Right now, if the phone is off and a message sent, if I turn it on, nothing will happen.

Comment: Tips for Developing a VoIP App - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13

Comment: Check out this blog about exactly this topic: https://blog.layer.com/how-we-leverage-ios-push-notifications/ it's a little old but everything is still accurate AFAIK. Best of luck.

Comment: @Rohit Not ure I can simplement that if the app does not allow Voice Calling. Apple might refuse the app.

Comment: @dylansturg I read the article, it is clear but it does not say how to solve the problem is talking about. (Of course, beside using their service).

Comment: The article explains how to use silent and not-silent push notifications to keep content up to date. Essentially you can use a silent push-notification to launch your app for a few minutes and download all of your users messages. If your app doesn't respond to the silent notification, then you can send out a push notification with an alert "Hey User, you've got messages... Tap here" and you just have to wait for the user to open the app again before you can download their messages. The article explains why both approaches together is beneficial.

Comment: Without bending the rules (and risking rejection), you really can't do any better than using push notifications when the app isn't running. Of course when your app is running (foreground or background) you can sync messages in whatever way you like. Which is why the silent push notifications (with background execution) are so powerful: you can sync with your messages backend without the user having to open your app.

Comment: @dylansturg thanks a lot for the answer. I am going to try it out as you said. WhatsApp for example, as soon as the phone is on or internet back on, you get the messages. Do you really thinks they said notification all the times until it gets through? For me, they have a way to informe the app about internet status and it is by using VoIP...

Comment: What do you mean "said notification all the times"? The author of the article describes sending 2 notifications: start with a silent push and wait for the app to respond by downloading messages. If the app doesn't respond, then just send a notification with an alert that there's a new message. If you want to use VoIP, then by all means, but you're deliberating violating Apple's guidelines if you're using VoIP for text messaging.

Comment: I meant "Send notification all the times". My issue is this one: If the phone is in airplane mode, I have no way to know that the notification went through and no way to know when the airplane mode is off so the phone is reachable again...  you see my point? I am just wondering how to make sure that the message is received as soon as possible.

Comment: Still trying to make it works if anyone has any idea that could help :)